# Safari driver wont close

Tags: selenium, safaridriver

Safari Driver closes the browser after automated test case have run but Safari browser instance hangs and I can still see it in the open apps. Any suggestion ? At the moment I am using the following snippet to shut the browser sessions (it works for chrome). Safari Version 11.0.3 (13604.5.6). Selenium 3.11. java version "1.8.0_171".

```
    if (System.getProperty("browser").equals("chrome") || System.getProperty("browser").equals("safari")) {
            driver.quit();
        }
```

Comment: why do you have condition to invoke quit?

Comment: I don't get it.

Comment: why don't you call driver.quit() without any "if"?

Comment: Because There are browsers where it is not needed.

Comment: you always need to call quit() to quit the browser

Comment: Guys, I am having a problem with Safari (this is the reason of my question). The browser closes the windows but the application itself is still running and you can find it in the open apps. The question is: how can I solve this issue ? Also, I am using driver.close() AND IF the browser is Safari OR Chrome I call driver.quit() as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your mileage may vary, but I had a similar issue and found a thread here: https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/9938 where the solution (with Appium at least and also woking in my current Selenium proj) is to wait before trying to quit the driver.

Comment: Would you mind to share the snippet that is working for you regarding the wait ? Thanks

Comment: public void CloseDriver()
         {
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            driver.Close();
            driver.Quit();
            Console.WriteLine("Driver Closed.");
        }